# String concatenation

Tags: c++, string

Why it is possible to do

```
const string exclam = "!";
const string str = exclam + "Hello" + " world";
```

And not possible to do this:

```
const string exclam = "!";
const string str = "Hello" + " world" + exclam;
```

I know (although can't understand why) that it is not allowed to do:

```
const string str = "Hello" + " world" + "!";
```

as it will be interpreted like `const char[6] + const char[6] + const char[1]`, so from other side, why this is not allowed also, or why it uses `char[]` and not `string`.

Comment: If you want to concatenate string literals, then don't use `+`: `const string str = "Hello" " world" + exclam;`

Comment: also checkout 
https://onlinegdb.com/rJxM4IugX

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `+` operator is left-associative (evaluated left-to-right), so the leftmost `+` is evaluated first.

`exclam` is a `std::string` object that overloads `operator+` so that both of the following perform concatenation:

```
exclam + "Hello"
"Hello" + exclam
```

Both of these return a `std::string` object containing the concatenated string.

However, if the first two thing being "added" are string literals, as in:

```
"Hello" + "World"
```

there is no class type object involved (there is no `std::string` here).  The string literals are converted to pointers and there is no built-in `operator+` for pointers.

Comment: @sbi : Operators never get evaluated, operands do.

Comment: @Prasoon: A valid nitpick which I can't do anything about because I cannot edit that comment anymore. (However, you don't answer my implied question.)

Comment: @sbi:  Such operators are called "left associative" in English too.  When I originally posted, I couldn't remember whether "X associative" meant the "X-most" operator was evaluated first or last (where "X" is "left" or "right").  Thanks.  @Prasoon:  Technically, _expressions_ get evaluated :-)

Comment: Thanks, now I know for sure! P.S.: I removed my comment, because now you incorporated in into your answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are concatanating `const char[6]` + `const char[6]`, which is not allowed, as you said.

In C++, string literals (stuff between quotes) are interpreted as `const char[]`s.

You can concatenate a `string` with a `const char[]` (and vice-versa) because the `+` operator is overridden in string, but it can't be overridden for a basic type.

Comment: @Philip:  A string literal has the type `const char[N]` where `N` is the size of the string literal.  It is an array, and like an array it can be implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element (a `const char*`).  In C++, while the conversion of a string literal to (non-`const`) `char*` is deprecated, it is still allowed.

Answer (score 3):

```
const string exclam = "!";    // Initialize a c++ string with an ansi c string
const string str = exclam + "Hello" + " world"; // Using the operator+ method of exclam
```

You can do it because the `operator+` of exclam will return a new string containing "!Hello", on which you subsequently call the `operator+` with " world" as parameter, so you get another string which, finally, gets assigned to str by means of the copy constructor.

On the other hand

```
const string str = "Hello" + " world" + exclam;
```

cannot be executed because "Hello" is just a `const char *`, which doesn't have a `operator+` taking a `const char *` as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

(New answer, this was not possible back in 2010)

You can now write

```
const string str = "Hello"s + " world"s + "!"s;
//                        ^           ^      ^
```

By adding that `s` after a string literal, you tell the compiler it's actually a `std::string` and not a `const char[]`. That means you can call members functions on it. E.g. `("ABC"s).back()` but also `+`

Comment: valid only for c++14   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers that explain the reason for your observations, I post here how to get rid of the problem (you might have figured this out already).

Replace

```
const string str = "Hello" + " world" + exclam;
```

with

```
const string str = string("Hello") + " world" + exclam;
```

so you make sure the first operand is a `string` and not a `const char[]`.