# How to 'plus' strings in C++

Tags: c++

Sorry, english is not my native language, then I have some doubt to create this question.

**I need to assign a code like:**

```
string mystr;
mystr = "a" + "b";
```

But I just get errors.
The problem is on the operator? Isn't + (plus)?

Yes, I'm novice programmer too.
Please, help.
Thank you so much.

Comment: _"But I just get errors."_ - What are the exact errors you get? You should include them along with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your post. Note the word _complete_.

Comment: @Mark Mor What is *string mystr;?

Comment: *string is probably a typo from the user making the text bold originally. I removed it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast response.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592357/string-concatenation, so no need to fix this question. We already have a good version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly then you can write for example

```
std::string mystr( "a" );
mystr +=  "b";
```

Or

```
std::string mystr;
// ...
mystr = std::string( "a" ) + "b";
```

Or

```
std::string mystr;
// ...
( mystr = "a" ) += "b";
```

Or

```
std::string mystr;
// ...
mystr.assign( "a" ).append( "b" );
```

So as you see it can be done in various ways.

operator + may not be overloaded for pointers. 
So this expression

```
"a" + "b"
```

is invalid.

For your code would work one of operands of operator + shall have type `std::string`.

If by some reason you need a pointer to an object of type std::string then you can write for example

```
std::string *mystr = new std::string( "a" );

*mystr += "b";
```

Comment: Thank you so much Vlad.
It was a valueble help.

Answer (score 0):

The operator+ is not defined for to char[]. When you type strings in cpp as "mystring" they are interpreted at const char arrays. The operator+ is defined for strings and char[] so this works

```
std::string mystr("thisisatring")
std::string otherstr = mystr + "otherstring"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's true that you can't add string literals with the '+' operator.
However, you can concatenate them without it. Simply remove your '+'.

```
string mystr;  
mystr = "a" "b";
```

Comment: Amazing! But when I concatenate with a variable?

Like:

mystr = "a" var "b";

?

Comment: @MarkMor: Only __adjacent string literals__ will be concatenated this way and that's only during compilation. So `"a" var "b"` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am using usually using pattern below.

```
std::string a = std::string{"something"} + std::string{" more"};
```