# How do implicit class construction work in C++?

Tags: c++

I created the following code for educational purposes and encountered a scenario for which I expected an error to occur, but no error occurred. Here is the class,

```
#include <string.h> // strcpy_s and strcat_s, not available in "<string>"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class String 
{
    char *p;
    int len;

public:
    String() {
        len = 0;
        p = '\0';
    };

    ~String() {
        delete p;
    };

    String(const char * s);
    String(const String & s);
    friend String operator+(const String& a, const String &);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, String const& m);

};

String::String(const char * s) 
{
    len = strlen(s);
    p = new char[len + 1];
    strcpy_s(p, len + 1,  s);
}

String operator+(const String & l, const String & r) {

    String temp;
    temp.len = l.len + r.len;
    int temp_buffer_size = temp.len + 1;

    temp.p = new char[temp_buffer_size];

    strcpy_s(temp.p, temp_buffer_size, l.p);
    strcat_s(temp.p, temp_buffer_size, r.p);
    return temp;
}

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, String const & m) {
    return os << m.p;
}

int main() {
    String right("right");
    
    String out = "left " + right + " ";
    std::cout << out;

    return 0;
}
```

If I run this code, it works fine. However my confusion comes from `String out = "left " + right + " ";`. Why does this line work, why did it not create an error such as "Cannot add `const char *` with `String`"? I am guessing here that it implicitly creates a `String` object while passing `"left"` as the constructor, but I was hoping for more evidence for this.

Comment: You should make the code in the question a [example] -- in this particular code, keeping only the #include and the `main` function is sufficient for the program to run. The other functions are unnecessary.

Comment: The compiler is allowed to try one conversion operation (over simplified) when trying to find a matching function to call. So in the partial expression `"left " + right` the function `String operator+(const String & l, const String & r)` is a match if `"left"` can be turned into `String`, which it can be via the constructor `String(const char * s);`   Try making the single argument constructors of the `String` class  `explicit` to get the error you expected.

Comment: Related but not the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592357/string-concatenation

Comment: The rules of the language (roughly speaking) allow a single conversion (calling a constructor that can accept a single argument) on one of the operands in an expression involving a single operand.  Addition is left-right associative so, for `String out = "left " + right + " "`, the compiler first tries to evaluate `"left " + right`, which can be done by performing a single conversion on `"left"` i.e. doing `operator+(String("left"), right)`.  That `operator+()` returns a `String`, so we're left with `operator+(...) + "right"`.  The same logic then applies with doing a conversion on `"right"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does this line work, why did it not create an error such as "Cannot add const char * with String"?

Because your `String` class has an *implicit* constructor from `const char*`. That allows the compiler to convert string literals to objects of type `String` *implicitly*, when needed.

So, when processing the `"left " + right` expression, the compiler searched for all matching `operators+` candidates and selected the best viable overload. In this example, `operator+(const String&, const String&)` is the only operator that can handle `right` argument. Hence the behavior. More details can be found in "[Overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution)".

To disable such conversion you should've declared the constructor explicit:

```
explicit String(const char * s);
```

then you'd get the error message.